# Why doesn't GDB show line numbers or function names?

Tags: gcc, gdb

I was trying to use GDB to troubleshoot a segfault in code I'm writing.  GDB does not show line numbers or function names when I use the `backtrace` command.  Here's a short sample program that illustrates my problem:

```
void segfault(int *b) {
    // This causes a segfault on CentOS7 Intel 64-bit
    b[-1] = 5;
}

void main() {
    int a[10];
    segfault(a);
}
```

However when I compile with

```
gcc -ggdb -O0 test.c -o segfaulttest
```

And use `gdb segfaulttest` to run it, when I use gdb's backtrace command I don't get any line numbers or function names.  I would expect it to list `main()` and `segfault()` in the trace.

Sample output

```
Reading symbols from /home/user/test/segfaulttest...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/test/segfaulttest 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000050040051c in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000050040051c in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

I'm using:

- CentOS 7 (64 bit)
- GCC: `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)`
- GDB is `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)`

(Aside: I fixed the actual bug in my code, I just don't understand why gdb backtrace doesn't show me more information).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have destroyed the part of the stack that contains the information gdb needs to know where your program is at.

```
0x000000050040051c in ?? ()
  ^^^^^^^^
```

This is the number 5 your code wrote, a 4 byte int.

When main() started, the return address is stored on the stack. The return address
is where main() will got back to when it is done. That place is a function that's part of the runtime that called main().

Since that return address is mangled/overwritten by your code, execution tries to jump back to some non-existing address, which causes the crash.

That address, 0x000000050040051c, is now the program counter register, which gets stored as the SIGSEGV signal is delivered to your process. gdb inspects this info, tries to figure out where the code matching the address 0x000000050040051c is located  - which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the quick, understandable answer.  I tried changing segfault() to this: `void segfault() { raise(SIGSEGV); }` and ran gdb again I  was able to successfully look at the stacktrace.